# Paging with a scrollview containing zoom enabled scrollviews inside

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scrollview

I have a `scrollview` with paging enabled. This `scrollview` contains **3 equally sized inner scrollviews**, and each inner `scrollview` contains an `imageview`.
I want to use the outer `scrollview` for paging through the three inner `scrollviews`, sort of like photos app. The inner `scrollviews` are for allowing to zoom into the `imageview` using the default pinch gesture.
So, I want it to be a photo browser that pages through photos, while I should be able to zoom any photo using pinch gesture.
But, swiping left or right does not do anything, which I expected will page through the three views. When I try pinch zooming, the first inner `scrollview` zooms in its `uiimageview`, and any horizontal or vertical scroll actions take place within that `scrollview` itself, I cannot page to the next inner `scrollview`. 
How do I accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial on this, actually: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html